# Correct interpretation of Scala Map's flatmap expression

Tags: scala

I am scratching my head vigorously, to understand the logic that produces the value out of a flatMap() operation:

```
val ys = Map("a" -> List(1 -> 11,1 -> 111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22,2 -> 222)).flatMap(e => {
     |    println("e =" + e)
     |    (e._2)
     | })
e =(a,List((1,11), (1,111)))
e =(b,List((2,22), (2,222)))
ys: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)
```

The *println* clearly shows that flatMap is taking in one entry out of the input *Map*. So, **e._2** is a List of Pairs. I can't figure out what exactly happens after that!

I am missing a very important and subtle step somewhere. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be thought of as:

First we map:

```
val a = Map("a" -> List(1 -> 11,1 -> 111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22,2 -> 222)).map(e => e._2) 
// List(List((1, 11), (1, 111)), List((2, 22), (2, 222)))
```

Then we flatten:

```
val b = a.flatten
// List((1, 11), (1, 111), (2, 22), (2, 222))
```

Then we convert back to a map:

```
b.toMap
// Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)
```

Since a map cannot have 2 values for 1 key, the value is overwritten.

---

Really whats going on is that the flatMap is being converted into a loop like so:

```
for (x <- m0) b ++= f(x)
```

where:

- m0 is our original map
- b is a collection builder that has to build a `Map`, aka, `MapBuilder`
- f is our function being passed into the flatMap (it returns a `List[(Int, Int)]`)
- x is an element in our original map

The `++=` function takes the list we got from calling `f(x)`, and calls `+=` on every element, to add it to our map. For a `Map`, `+=` just calls the original `+` operator for a `Map`, which updates the value if the key already exists.

Finally we call `result` on our builder which just returns us our `Map`.

Comment: The elaboration through _map_, followed by _flatten_, was crisp. Fantastic. That point missed me somehow! Many thanks. @soote